# Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409) STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I have created a pure `Python` project in PyCharm and imported `numpy`, `tensorflow` and `opencv` in order to test a small program.

All packages are updated to the latest version.My `Python` version is `3.6.4` and I am running on `Windows x64`. I have browsed through all the solutions on related threads that suggested updating `NVIDIA` driver, but I have an `Intel` driver.

Here is the logged error:

```
Faulting application name: python.exe, version: 3.6.4150.1013, time stamp: 0x5a38b889  
Faulting module name: ucrtbase.dll, version: 10.0.16299.248, time stamp: 0xe71e5dfe  
Exception code: 0xc0000409  
Fault offset: 0x000000000006b79e  
Faulting process ID: 0x4004  
Faulting application start time: 0x01d3c1ef8a3d751c  
Faulting application path: C:\Users\xtr\Test\TfLayers\Scripts\python.exe  
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll  
Report ID: e96d98cb-28c9-4340-bcd3-a7033d4b4972  
Faulting package full name:   
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Comment: I have the same error code. `Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)`. Running TF/Keras with a Conda environment running Python 3.5

Comment: Do you have an Intel GPU? As far as I know, tensorflow won't run on anything but NVIDIA GPUs, unless you're using a fork.

Comment: I got the same problem.
I am running Tensorflow with the default Anaconda environment.
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 (2 GB GDDR5 dedicated)
CPU: Intel Core i7-7700HQ (2.8 GHz base frequency, up to 3.8 GHz with Intel Turbo Boost Technology, 6 MB cache, 4 cores)

If I remember correctly I installed Tensorflow for CPU, I have been able to run Tensorflow without any problems previously.

Answer (score 4):

This was solved by installing pyqt. I installed pyqt with the command (from conda-forge)

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyqt
```

Comment: pycharm debugger: pycharm process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xc0000005), solved by this solution.

Comment: Strangely I still have the the error even after reinstallation of the referred package (I had it before running into the error). Could you have a look at my answer if you have an idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was obsolete pyqt library. The following worked for me:

```
conda install -c anaconda pyqt
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem does not come from PyCharm, if you use any other IDEs, the result would be the same. In fact, they all use a package called `pydev` to debug. Your best bet would be to create a brand new Python environment (PyCharm has a function for this) and gradually install packages.

If the solution works and you can find out which package conflicts with `pydev`, it will be most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and bumped into this question, but for a different reason which I want to present in case somebody else faces the same situation. I already had `pyqt` installed as mentioned in other answers. But, just to be sure and according to the unspoken "did you try restarting" principle, I reinstalled `pyqt` in my `conda` env alongside `PyQt5` (and also `PyQt6`) - bot PyQts installed via `pip`.

No idea why and sadly I do not have the time to debug it, but `PyQt6` was the problematic part in my code (which I am trying for the 1st time). My minimal test code is as follows and includes two subversions denoted by `v1` and `v2`. I hope that part is obvious:

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget  # v1
# from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget  # v2
import sys
q = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QWidget()
w.show()  # in debug mode, ran ok till here (?)
sys.exit(q.exec())  # for `v1` from above
# sys.exit(q.exec_())  # for `v2` from above
```

The code variation `v2` is working while `v1` throws the same error mentioned by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I created an object inherited by `QThread` and started thread without saving object as object variable.

When launched in debug mode everything was fine, when launched without debugging the program crashed with code: `-1073740791 (0xC0000409)`

Before:

```
def showEvent(self, event):
    super().showEvent(event)
    thread = QThreadWithSignal(self.__upload)
    thread.signal.connect(self.__show_error_message)
    thread.start()
```

After:

```
def showEvent(self, event):
    super().showEvent(event)
    self.thread = QThreadWithSignal(self.__upload)
    self.thread.signal.connect(self.__show_error_message)
    self.thread.start()
```